# Referencing Terraform instance attributes to user data during creation of EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How can I pass the `public_dns` value of the `aws_instance` resource to the `user_data` section ?

```
resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami                    = "ami-04ad2567c9e3d7893"
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.web-sg.name]


  user_data = <<-EOF
                  #!/bin/bash
                  sudo su
                  echo "<p> The Public DNS of instance: ${self.app_server.public_dns} </p>" >> index.html
                  python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
                  EOF
  tags = {
    Name = "web_instance"
  }

}
```

I tried with `self` or with `aws_instance.app_server.public_dns` declaration but none of them worked with getting the following error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public dns will become available after the instance has started. It isn't possible to reference it in user data. You can read it though with this command:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

Comment: Is the IP in the curl statement the Public IP of the EC2 instance? If so, how do you pass the public IP address to user data? I'm guessing this is also only available after the instance has started...

Comment: It is safe to hardcode this IP, it isn't the public IP of the instance. Read in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html